# Spark join throws 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id' error. How could I fix it?

Tags: python, sql, function, join, apache-spark

I am making a query in Spark in Databricks, and I have a problema when I am trying to make a join between two dataframes. The two dataframes that I have are the next ones:

- "names_df" which has 2 columns: "ID", "title" that refer to the id and the title of films.

  ```
  +-------+-----------------------------+
  |ID     |title                        |
  +-------+-----------------------------+
  |1      |Toy Story                    |
  |2      |Jumanji                      |
  |3      |Grumpier Old Men             |
  +-------+-----------------------------+
  ```
- "info" which has 3 columns: "movieId", "count", "average" that refer to the id of the film, the number of ranks that it has, and the average of those ratings.

  ```
  +-------+-----+------------------+
  |movieId|count|average           |
  +-------+-----+------------------+
  |1831   |7463 |2.5785207021305103|
  |431    |8946 |3.695059244355019 |
  |631    |2193 |2.7273141814865483|
  +-------+-----+------------------+
  ```

This "info" dataframe was created this way:

```
info =  ratings_df.groupBy('movieId').agg(F.count(ratings_df.rating).alias("count"), F.avg(ratings_df.rating).alias("average"))
```

Where "ratings_df" is another dataframe that contains 3 columns: "userId", "movieId" and "rating", that refer to the id of the user that voted, the id of the film that the user voted to, and the rating for that film:

```
+-------+-------+-------------+
|userId |movieId|rating       |
+-------+-------+-------------+
|1      |2      |3.5          |
|1      |29     |3.5          |
|1      |32     |3.5          |
+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I am trying to make a join between these two dataframes to get another one with those columns: "movieId", "title", "count", "average":

```
+-------+-----------------------------+-----+-------+
|average|title                        |count|movieId|
+-------+-----------------------------+-----+-------+
|5.0    |Ella Lola, a la Trilby (1898)|1    |94431  |
|5.0    |Serving Life (2011)          |1    |129034 |
|5.0    |Diplomatic Immunity (2009? ) |1    |107434 |
+-------+-----------------------------+-----+-------+
```

So the operation I did was the next one:

```
movie_names_df = info.join(movies_df, info.movieId == movies_df.ID, "inner").select(movies_df.title, info.average, info.movieId, info.count).show()
```

The problem is that I get the next error message:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

And I know that this error occurs because it consider that info.count is a function, and not an attribute, as I defined previously.

So, how could I make that join correctly to get what I want?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried to use the alternative column access using brackets? E.g. `info["count"]`?

Comment: Thank you! That's it! I was trying to make it using parenthesis. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adding comment as answer since it solved the problem. `count` is somewhat of a protected keyword in DataFrame API, so naming columns *count* is dangerous. In your case you could circumvent the error by not using the dot notation, but bracket based column access, e.g.

```
info["count"]
```

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with a column named `alias`.  Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Same here with `sample`!

Comment: Is there a full list of reserved keywords somewhere?

Comment: I had the same problem with `name`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get `info.count` as a function call `info.count()`.

```py
movie_names_df = info.join(movies_df, info.movieId == movies_df.ID, "inner").select(movies_df.title, info.average, info.movieId, info.count()).show()
```